# Simply null check + property access

Tags: c#, properties, null, call

Is there an operator to simplify this operation in C# to avoid null pointer exceptions?

```
obj == null ? null : obj.Property;
```

Something like

```
obj?.Property;
```

I really want to get rid of NullReferenceExeptions

Comment: Yes, it's exactly what you wrote... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators

Comment: I guess you should be more explicit about what you mean by `attribute`. An `Attribute` cannot be accessed via `variable.Attribute` or `type.Attribute` anyway, so the question doesn't make sense. Please show your _actual_ code. - But if you mean a _property_ instead of an _attribute_, then you already showed the correct syntax.

Comment: yes, i meant property, i edited the post, thanks guys

Comment: **update:** im using C# version 5 so i can't use that operator :(

Comment: Then you'll have to keep checking for null, unfortunately.

Comment: @SirHectorin any reason you can't use C# 6? You just need VS 2015 or later.

Comment: @CharlesMager i recently got hired in a company and they gave me a ASP.NET project written in C# 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @canton7 said, you answered your own question.
The `?.` operator actually exists in C#

Here's a small example showing how it prevents the `NullReferenceException`

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> list = GetList();
        Console.WriteLine($"{list?.Count}");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static List<string> GetList()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```